# What is the difference between \bool_if_p:N and \bool_if:NTF

Tags: expl3, latex3

What is the difference between `\bool_if_p:N` and `\bool_if:NFT`? How to use these commands?

The documentation does not provide any details on this.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at section "9.1 Defining a set of conditional functions" from `texdoc interface3` for a better grasp at the differences. But `\bool_if_p:N` is a predicate which "returns" either true or false, whereas `\bool_if:NFT` is a function which has a true and a false branches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is documented, but not for this specific function, rather at the beginning, which applies to all `expl3` conditionals:

> [image]

---

The `:NTF` form is a branching conditional, and you use it like:

```latex
\bool_if:NTF \l_my_bool
  { <code if true> }
  { <code if false> }
```

and the `_p:N` form is a “predicate” conditional, and you use it as part of a boolean expression:

```latex
%              vvvvvvvvvvvv
\bool_if:nTF { \bool_if_p:N \l_my_bool || \tl_if_exist_p:N \l_my_tl }
  { <code if true> }
  { <code if false> }
```

In short: the predicate form returns a value, while the branching form executes some code.

Note that the predicate form is not available in non-expandable conditional functions (e.g. `l3regex` conditionals).